# Can I play sound from USB, Not from sound card?

Tags: power-supply, usb, output, sound-card

I made an FM radio transmitter circuit and it works. It is supplied using a 12 volts transformer. The input of the transmitter is connected to the output of my PC's sound card (just like the way we connect PC loud speaker).

I would like to supply it using USB so that I no longer need external transform, That is fine for me and I think I can do it.

What I'm asking about is how to connect D+ and D- to the input of the transmitter? I don't want to use sound card any more. I need my transmitter to have USB cable only. Is there any software or method that when I play a music, the music is out from D+ and D- not from sound card socket.
Music can be transferred to flash memory through USB (D+ and D-), Can I transfer it to the transmitter the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot "play music" just like that through the USB D+ and D- datalines. USB is a two-way data communication protocol so if you want to use it to play music you have to use something that can output audio and has a USB connection.

Also your transmitter needs an analog audio signal as input signal, that's why you need to connect it to your soundcard.

I propose that you get a cheap [USB sound card](http://www.ebay.nl/itm/USB-2-0-Audio-Headset-Microphone-Jack-Converter-Sound-Card-Adapter-PY-/311445488035?hash=item48839901a3), it has USB on one side and a headphone socket on the other side. If you combine this with your transmitter you can transmit audio over FM and only use the USB cable for sound and supplying 5V to the transmitter.

Comment: That's a great idea to use a usb soundcard!

Answer (score 0):

Not without a usb driver on the pc so your operating system saw the transmitter as an audio out device.

I guess you could probably try making a custom usb cable that you split out the data lines and attached them to the motherboard speaker jumpers.